# PHP/JS : Sending Direct Print command to printer

Tags: javascript, printing

I am working on a Codeigniter Project where a pdf file has to be printed.

The printer is connected to the system through a cable. If I use `window.print();` I get the file in a print dialogue, but my requirement is to directly print the file without showing the popup.

Can someone please help me to achieve this, I tried the below code that did not work

```html
<button onclick="printPage()">print</button>
<div id="printerDiv" style="display:none"></div>
<script>
  function printPage() {
    var div = document.getElementById("printerDiv");
    div.innerHTML = '<iframe src="mypage.aspx" onload="this.contentWindow.print();"></iframe>';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Browsers don't have that level of control. Imagine for a minute that you are on a website and all of a sudden your printer starts spitting out pages. That would be terrifying and is essentially what you are asking for. Also the following issues: 1.) The user might not want their default printer, 2.) The user might decide they don't want to print it, 3.) they might want a PDF instead and use the print dialog to do it...

Comment: Server side it is doable!

Answer (score 0):

you can print directly to any printer using PHP.
I am using PHP for printing.

you can use [mike42 escpos github](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php) plugin.

after download you need to make a connector for your printer.
use [this](https://github.com/mike42/escpos-php#using-a-printconnector)

after you can print.